# Selecting mysql database cells in c#

Tags: c#, mysql, unity-game-engine

What im trying to do is select a cell where my username is and compare the password to the text this is done in unity c# but im using Mysql Reference it should be like any type of c#. Now im trying to do something similar in vb when you read the value in the reader it will look like this in vb 
rdr(0) but i can't seem to do this in c# here is my code. For anyone worried about where the password goes I planned on adding encryption later.

```
void Login_Data(string un, string pw) {
        con = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);
        con.Open();
        Debug.Log("Mysql state: " + con.State);

        string sql = "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE '" + un + "'";
        cmd = new MySqlCommand(sql, con);
        rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        while (rdr.Read()) {
                if (rdr[3] == pw) // this is the problem it keeps warning 
//me i like my stuff clean but i dont risk errors if (rdr[3] == pw) also 
//it did give me an error but not here.

                {
                    username = un;
                    MessageBox.Show(username + ", Has Logged in!", "API");
                    usertext.text = "User: " + username;
                    m_uid.text = "UserID: " + rdr.GetString("uid");
                }
        }
}
```

Warning CS0252  Possible unintended reference comparison; to get a value comparison, cast the left hand side to type 'string'

I don't understand this warning or why its occurring

Comment: just note im not the best at c# im far from it.

Comment: Its warning you with....what warning? Also, this is a terrible way to validate user login...(1) your database shouldn't store a plaintext password and (2) is should not ***send that password to the requestor!***

Comment: i just started on this script im still figuring out how to use mysql.

Comment: i added the warning happy?

Comment: sharing is caring.. but seriously, it always helps to provide all the info

Comment: i know i just forgot to add some info when i created the post.

Comment: What is the value of the variable _un_ This code should fail with a syntax error. Are you posting your exact code?  _WHERE '" + un + "'_

Comment: https://coding.abel.nu/2014/09/net-and-equals/

Comment: draco18s i'll try that

Comment: the other code is just a button listener for when the submit button is click it sends the values so say un = "big bob" think of it like that.

Comment: Please get a book or read a tutorial on ADO.NET, this stuff is simply too complicated to try to guess your way through it.

Comment: I don't guess my way through it if i did that i would never get anywhere. im primarily a vb developer but c# is simple. im not doing .NET in this this is UnityEngine C# and has little reference support for older .NET frameworks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a one line fix :

```
.... if (rdr[3].ToString() == pw).....
```

The reason you are getting the error is because you are comparing a data-cell to a data-type...

But let's learn a little more, shall we?

Firstly, your SQL statement makes no sense. Let's take a look at it:

```
"SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE '" + un + "'"
```

So, you are using the `Where` clause. Let's speak of general grammar. When we use any word related to `WH`, aren't we supposed to give information about something? Like, you cannot just say :

> Brian went to New Jersey Where...

Instead, you could say :

> Brian went to New Jersey Where he left his browser cookies.

Same rule applies to SQL statements. When you use the `Where` clause, you are actually checking if some value matches with given value....

Here's what a proper usage of a `Where` statement looks like :

```
Select * From Table Where Column1 = 'Some Value'
```

Moving on...

You are using a `IDataReader` here which is pretty much unnecessary. Why not just compare all the values within the SQL statement itself ? Just use an `AND` to do multiple comparisons...

And as you mentioned you are storing Usernames and Passwords in the database. The best practice is to store the Username and the **hash** of the password. For that, you have tons of options to choose from such as **Argon2, bcrypt, scrypt, or PBKDF2**.

Last but not the least, the biggest problem with your code is the following line :

```
MessageBox.Show(username + ", Has Logged in!", "API");
```

After struggling for years, developers came with patters such as MVVM for scalability, performance and what not. Then why are you living in the 17th century? Always remember :

> You will spend 20% time writing the codes & 80% time in maintaining it.

So, don't write such UI related codes in the UI thread itself. If you are familiar with the MVVM pattern, you already know what i'm talking about...

Anyways, hope your learned something... And if i was wrong somewhere, feel free to correct it. Kapeesh ?

Comment: thanks man i also found another fix as well draco18s commented on how strings work in c# my vb knowledge got in the way! thanks for the answer yours was similar to mine! mine is just a bit straight forward and less talking.

Comment: If the answer helped, you can mark it as the answer for future reference... Happy coding buddy

Comment: i just implemented an encryption system its secure to the max.

Comment: @Kilo Don't just hash, [salt and hash](https://crackstation.net/hashing-security.htm#salt).

Comment: @Draco18s, agreed :)

Comment: @draco18s Don`t worry its a custom script with good cryptography but if base64 is something i need to worry about then be open about it and ill look for something better.

Comment: @Kilo Good cryptography isn't enough. If two people have the same password, it doesn't matter what crypto system you use: they're going to have the same hash. That's why you need the salt.

Comment: @Kilo, one quick suggestion : You should add special characters such as `$@~` with each string(password) passed before hashing+salting them for a stronger encryption.

Comment: "The reason you are getting the error is because you are comparing a data-cell to a data-type" Not quite right; reader(x) returns and object and you can't compare an object to a string. DataReaders don't have cells. The best way is `reader.GetString(x)` see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/retrieving-data-using-a-datareader

Comment: I broke this system down and put this project to rest a while ago, I'm feeling the ich to revive it. I want to put the knowledge that I've learned recently into it. I also want to know more about not coding on the UI thread so much, but I just get dead ends.

Answer (score 0):

I now know that strings like this pw.Equals(rdr[3]) can't be contained like this if (rdr[3] == pw)

```
void Login_Data(string un, string pw) {
    try {

        con = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);
        con.Open();
        Debug.Log("Mysql state: " + con.State);

        string sql = "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE uname='" + un + "'";
        cmd = new MySqlCommand(sql, con);
        rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        while (rdr.Read())
        {
                if (pw.Equals(rdr[3]))
                {
                    username = un;
                    MessageBox.Show(username + ", Has Logged in!", "API");
                    usertext.text = "User: " + username;
                    m_uid.text = "UserID: " + rdr.GetString("uid");
                }
        }
 }
```

it worked out thanks to draco18s and zack raiyan they gave me some new knowledge.